# Copy ActiveDirectory user

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to copy an existing AD user to a new user with this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP.Entry(), LDAP.User(), LDAP.PW());
entry.CopyTo(new DirectoryEntry("CN=UserToCopy,OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=local"), "NewUserName");
```

This gives the error:

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'unspecified error'"

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.copyto?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry_CopyTo_System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry_System_String_), `entry` should be the object you want to copy, and the first parameter is the *parent* of the new object (an OU). Something like this:

```
entry.CopyTo(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=local"), "NewUserName");
```

*Update:* Two years later and I find out that this just won't work for AD objects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62901233/1202807) for more details.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have done so far, but that throws the error.

Comment: You have `new DirectoryEntry("CN=UserToCopy,OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=local")`. Notice the `CN=UserToCopy` - that's a user, not an OU.

Comment: OK, but how do I then specify wich user to copy? I tryed to remove CN=usertocopy, but it gave the same error.

Comment: The user you want to copy is `entry`.

Comment: Could you please write the complete code for this example. I do not understand where the user to copy are defined.

Comment: You define the user to copy in the first line in your example: `entry = new DirectoryEntry(...)`

Comment: Tried this: DirectoryEntry entry1 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=MyName,OU=MyOU,OU=AnotherOU,DC=Domain,DC=local", BEOF_LDAP.User(), BEOF_LDAP.PW());
            
            entry1.CopyTo(new DirectoryEntry("OU=OU=MyOU,OU=AnotherOU,DC=Domain,DC=local"), "Test"); Gave the same error.

Comment: You have `OU=OU=`. It should be just one `OU=`.

Comment: That was just a typo here, the error is still there without double ou=

Comment: Oh, sorry. I see the problem. I'm surprised I didn't notice earlier. You need "LDAP://" in the path for the OU too: `new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=OU=MyOU,OU=AnotherOU,DC=Domain,DC=local")`.